# Error when trying to run python scripts

Tags: raspbian, python, linux, python-3, debian

I've been trying for a while now to run python scripts and everytime i try i get an error saying some package is missing. My conda environment path is set to:

```
root  /home/pi/miniconda3
```

where root is my environment name.

The python version that i am using is: `3.9.0`

I've tried to run inferencing using [google edge tpu](https://github.com/google-coral/tflite/tree/master/python/examples/classification). When i do, ./install_requirements.sh

I get the following error:

```
/home/pi/miniconda3/bin/python3: No module named pip
```

I have also tried running a neural network that i have downloaded from [here](https://github.com/yinguobing/cnn-facial-landmark):
What i did was open run from inside the folder

```
python3 landmark.py \
    --train_record=train.record \
    --val_record=validation.record \
    --batch_size=32 \
    --epochs=10
```

And i got

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "landmark.py", line 6, in <module>
    import numpy as np
ImportError: No module named 'numpy'
```

In both cases whichever folder i try to start the enviroment by doing conda install numpy or whatever package i always get a conflict message saying:

```
Error: Unsatisfiable package specifications.
Generating hint: 
[      COMPLETE      ]|###################################################| 100%


Hint: the following packages conflict with each other:
  - numpy
  - python 3.4*
```

What i am trying to do is run scripts without having to install those packages everytime i start my environment, and i also would like to know if it's obligatory to run python scripts in the prompt?

Comment: disregard previous comment ... I didn't notice you're using python 3.9, not the one that is standard 3.7.x

Comment: Nothing to do with the Pi.  The Pi comes with Python 3.  You would be better off using the installed version.